# HTTP requests.post timeout

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

In my code below, I use `requests.post`. What are the possibilities to simply continue if the site is down?

I have the following code:

```
def post_test():

    import requests

    url = 'http://example.com:8000/submit'
    payload = {'data1': 1, 'data2': 2}
    try:
        r = requests.post(url, data=payload)
    except:
        return   # if the requests.post fails (eg. the site is down) I want simly to return from the post_test(). Currenly it hangs up in the requests.post without raising an error.
    if (r.text == 'stop'):
        sys.exit()  # I want to terminate the whole program if r.text = 'stop' - this works fine.
```

How could I make the requests.post timeout, or return from post_test() if example.com, or its /submit app is down?

Answer (score 86, accepted):

Use the `timeout` parameter:

```
r = requests.post(url, data=payload, timeout=1.5)
```

> Note: `timeout` is not a time limit on the entire response download;
>   rather, an exception is raised if the server has not issued a response
>   for `timeout` seconds (more precisely, if no bytes have been received on
>   the underlying socket for `timeout` seconds). If no timeout is specified
>   explicitly, requests do not time out.

Comment: are you still sure if no timeout is specified exlicitly, requests don't timeout. The thing is I tried it out and it seems they do timeout automatically !

Comment: They don't time out because of Python, but because of the server timing out, which is outside of the control of your code.

Comment: so you meant, the timeout will be counted from when the server received the request at the server side? OR is it counted from when client's requesting? I guess it was counted from when the server received the request. Thanks

Comment: Its interesting: pylint gives you hint about timeout, and I wonder if socket-functions at all could have no timeout. Would mean a request will always timeout.

Answer (score 32):

All requests take a timeout keyword argument. <sup>[1](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/v2.21.0/requests/api.py#L34)</sup>

The `requests.post` is simply forwarding its arguments to `requests.request` <sup>[2](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/v2.21.0/requests/api.py#L116)</sup>

When the app is down, a `ConnectionError` is more likely than a `Timeout`. <sup>[3](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/v2.21.0/docs/user/quickstart.rst#errors-and-exceptions)</sup>

```
try:
    requests.post(url, data=payload, timeout=5)
except requests.Timeout:
    # back off and retry
    pass
except requests.ConnectionError:
    pass
```