# Put a time limit on a request

Tags: python, python-requests

I have a program and in order verify that the user doesnt download such big files using input i need a time limit on how long each request is allowed to take.

Does anyone know a good way to put a time limit(/lifetime) on each python requests get requests so if it takes 10 seconds an exception will be thrown.

Thanks

Comment: requests take a `timeout` parameter. Although that timeout means that if any of the underlying socket operations take 10 seconds the request will be cancelled, not 10 seconds for the entire request. It's one of the big caveats of requests, but it works well enough in practice. https://vorpus.org/blog/timeouts-and-cancellation-for-humans/

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54619868/http-requests-post-timeout

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HTTP requests.post timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54619868/http-requests-post-timeout)

Answer (score 1):

You can define your own timeout like:

```
requests.get('https://github.com/', timeout=0.001)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass an additional *timeout* parameter to every request you make. This is always recommended as it will make your code more robust to hanging indefinitely in case you don't receive a response from the other end.

```
requests.get('https://github.com/', timeout=0.001)
```

Read the official python request documentation for timeouts [here](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/#timeouts).

Comment: No, I think we answered almost at the same time. This is just an example from official python requests documentation.